# jquery live is not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use the live() function of jquery(). But i dont know why but it is not working. Please help me.

```
$("#button_suchen").click(function(){
     $(".search_listing_content").append("< div class="listing dunkel">

< div class="listing_add" style="width:30px;height:30px;"></div>< div class="listing_name">Sepp Forcher</div></div>");
              });

     $(".listing_add").live("click",function(){
            alert("yes");
    });
```

Comment: avoid using live(), use on() or delegate() instead.

Comment: What version of jQuery, I believe it's removed in 1.9 (or, possibly, 2+).

Comment: From the official website:

As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

Answer (score 1):

Live is deprecated since jQuery 1.7 and removed in 1.9.0 use .on() instead

```
$('.listing_add').on('click',function(){...});
```

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Try this, you should not have to but it might work  `$(document).on('click','.listing_add',function(){...});`

Comment: omg its working.. :O THANK YOU SO MUCH!! i was searching now for 2 hours :)

Answer (score 1):

try this. Move your js code to document [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) as well.

```
$(function(){

  $(document).on("click",".listing_add",function(){
    alert("yes");
  });

});
```

Comment: It doesn't need to be in document ready if you're binding to the document.